# Display all the dates in week numbers in UNIX

Tags: date

I know the command to get the week number of a date is `date +%W`

Output: `03`

Now, is there a way of giving a week number it will display all the dates in that week? Or should I write a script?

Eg:

Input: `03`

Output:

```
Jan 20
Jan 21
Jan 22
Jan 23
Jan 24
Jan 25
Jan 26
```

First week (Jan 1, 2, 3,4 and 5) are considered as week no '0'. So the first week starts from 6th jan(First Monday in Jan 2014), 2nd week starts from 13th and third week starts from 20th

Comment: What platform are you running on? `uname -a`

Comment: Your week has only 6 days? And the week number seems not to be based on the ISO standard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date, what standard do you follow for numbering?

Comment: What distro? Do you have ncal?

Comment: Hi its  x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: The week has 7 days starting from Monday

Comment: Jan 20
Jan 21
Jan 22
Jan 23
Jan 24
Jan 25 
Jan 26

Comment: The ISO week has 7 days starting from Monday as well. But ISO week 03 of 2014 starts on Jan 13th, so **again** what standard or pattern are you following? Please clarify why this is week #3 and not #4 as with ISO

Comment: @RakeshK: I'm confused. Does the 3rd week start on the 19th or the 20th. Can you please edit your question to maek that apparent?

Comment: So Jan 5th this year is no week number at all (not in 0 and not in week 1)? And Jan 1-4 are always week 0, also when Jan 1st of a year is a Monday? Please update your Q with a coherent and understandable set of rules and preferably a reference to some standard for week numbering.

Comment: hi.. Done.. Anyways.. The only solution is write a script anyways. I have it already. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to rip this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606567/unix-date-how-to-convert-week-number-to-a-date-range-mon-sun) and further adapt it to your question:

```
#!/bin/bash
week=$1 year=$2
date_fmt="+%b %d"

week_num_of_Mon_1=$(date -d $year-01-01 +%W)
week_day_of_Mon_1=$(date -d $year-01-01 +%u)

if ((week_num_of_Mon_1)); then
   first_Mon=$year-01-01
else
   first_Mon=$year-01-$((01 + (7 - week_day_of_Mon_1 + 1) ))
fi

for nr_of_day_of_week in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
do
    day_of_week=$(date -d "$first_Mon +$((week - 1)) week + $nr_of_day_of_week day" "$date_fmt")
    echo $day_of_week
done
```

Example: `weekof 17 2014`
Result:

```
Apr 28
Apr 29
Apr 30
May 01
May 02
May 03
May 04
```

Comment: Please note that is not the ISO standard week number. It is the week starting with the 17th Monday in 2014.

Comment: Thanks Timo.. So basically we need a script .. can not be done in command line

Answer (score 2):

`ncal -w` gives you week numbers and you could parse the output using `awk`.

What I found easier is install the `python-dateutil` package and use:

```
import sys, datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, MO

week = int(sys.argv[1])
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    year = datetime.date.today().year
else:
    year = int(sys.argv[2])

beginning = datetime.date(year, 1, 1) + \
    relativedelta(day = 4, weekday = MO(-1), weeks = week-1)

for i in range(7):
    print beginning
    beginning += datetime.timedelta(1)
```

This gives you the 7 days based on the [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) week number.